# "Disciplined" badge working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, disciplined-badge

616 people seem to have it, but I just met the stated conditions and remain badgeless and afraid.

---

*relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069470/how-to-get-my-submenus-to-disppear-after-a-certain-period-using-javascript/1069625#1069625) if it matters (and you're allowed to view it)*

Comment: I think it's been stuck at 616 (the real number of the beast) for a few weeks.

Comment: The last two appear to have been awarded on June 14th... maybe it has frozen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, maybe Disciplined is broken, as it was last awarded [over 2 weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20946?tab=recent). Still, even though badges usually take maybe ~5 minutes, it's possible this is on an hourly or daily (or, perhaps, bi-weekly(!) cycle)

**edit:** looks like [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13018?tab=recent#sort-top) (along with 266 others) were just awarded it a few hours ago

Comment: accepted for now, given lack of evidence to the contrary

Comment: yep I did catch it today which means it's either not on a trigger (how quaint!) or it *is* buggy. Question may as well be closed until further evidence.

Answer (score 2):

The "Disciplined" badge was just awarded to me today; however, I'm not sure exactly what it was awarded for as I can't seem to remember deleting an answer recently. So it does appear that it is being awarded, but it might be bugged for some reason.

Comment: Me too - I've no idea what I recently deleted. :-(

Comment: I also just got this badge but I don't think I deleted _anything_ on the site yet.

Comment: Well, it's not being awarded to *everyone* as only 883 people currently have the badge, and there are many more users than that. ;)

Comment: +1 / Me too - I too recently (a couple of days ago) got this badge, even though I'm quite sure that I didn't delete any questions.

Answer (score 1):

A quick survey of recent recipients of the "Disciplined" badge reveals people who received it on June 14th, 13th, 12th and earlier. So it's not on a bi-weekly cycle or anything like that.

However, there doesn't appear to be any Disciplined badges awarded more recently than June 14th at the time of this post. I'd speculate that the badge is either broken or it requires some kind of manual action that has not been recently performed.

---

As of 8 July 2009, it looks like the Disciplined badge is being awarded again. There are now [883 people with the Disciplined badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined), up from 616 yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as Rob and the rest; recently awarded the badge, but to my knowledge, I've never deleted a post. I also feel conflicted about reporting it because I like getting badges, and now it will probably be revoked D:

Answer (score 0):

How long has it been? It can take some time before the system awards it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better question is: does the badge still make sense?  Do we really want to encourage people to delete something that at least three other users have found useful?

Deletion of posts has become a rather discouraged practice in the time since SO was first launched.

Comment: Back when it was first introduced, I questioned its wisdom on UV http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/37880-disciplined-badge-perhaps-a-bad-idea-?lang=en Since then I don't think that it's been as bad as I've predicted, but I still think that the majority of users with the badge deleted something just to get it, rather than deleting it because it was a duplicate or unhelpful.

Comment: Yes absolutely you do if it's wrong, and plenty of wrong answers got upvotes. You want to encourage correct answers, regardless of how helpful the wrong ones are.

Comment: I got it from being disciplined because someone else came along and provided a better answer after mine...

Comment: And likewise if there are two largely identical votes, both with upvotes, it makes sense to combine the two and delete one of them.

Comment: I got mine by deleting a community wiki post that had later been merged into the overall, definitive answer (it was on the "free programming books" question). I think I've deleted a non-CW post with 3 upvotes since then, though, so I would have gotten it anyway.